# У родовому відмінку вживаємо Гузара чи Гузаря?

Tags: іменники, відмінювання

Цікавить, до якої групи (тверда чи м’яка) належить прізвище Гузар. Відповідно звідси зможу правильно визначити закінчення. У просторах інтернету використано два варіанти:

> Салон [Гузаря](http://v.lutsk.ua/catalog/beauty/beauty-salon/salon-guzarya.html);
>
> Любомир Гузар народився 26 лютого 1933 в родині Ярослава [Гузара](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80_(%D0%93%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80))

То до якої групи все ж належить прізвище Гузар? А звідси — як же правильно: Гузара чи Гузаря?

P. S. : знаю, що слово "Ігор" згадується як виняток і належить до м’якої групи. Про це йдеться навіть у підготовці до ЗНО. Однак про слово "Гузар" ніде не згадано.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У [Блозі проф. Пономарева](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-40888043)  знаходимо відповідь на це запитання:
**Гузар** - того самого походження, що й гусар - військовий легкої кінноти. І загальне слово, й прізвище є іменниками **твердої групи**, тому кажемо **Гузар, Гузара, Гузаром.**

Comment: A [Ігор](/q/3119) з јого [етімолоґіјеју](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ігор#Етимологія)?

Comment: Ім'я "Ігор" належить до іменників м'якої групи, тому відмінюємо його так: "Ігор" - "Ігоря", "Ігореві", "Ігоря", "Ігорем", "на Ігореві". Кличний відмінок - "Ігорю".(http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/ukrainian/ponomariv,    http://pravopys.kiev.ua/pravopys.aspx?SectionID=1774). А до твердої групи належать іменники ч. р.  з постійно наголошеними -ар (-яр), -ир. "Ігор" більше як виняток.